# Is this an error in htaccess or apache config?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I was using xampp before but switch to individual setup for php-mysql. In my xampp everything works perfectly. But when I migrated my code to my new setup I can’t login to my application.

This is the step

```
1. http://localhost/login - //user input username & password
2. http://localhost/login/validate_credentials - //error occurred URL NOT FOUND:     localhost/login/validate_credentials
```

I traced the problem this what I found out. If I add index.php before the 1st segment(http://localhost/index.php/login/validate_credentials) in my uri I am now able to login. But what is really mess up is I can’t access all my other methods without adding index.php first. So I guess my problem is my htaccess.

This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

I enabled the mod_rewrite in my http.conf. In my xampp 1.7.3 all my methods works without index.php.

Comment: webmasters.stackexchange.com maybe?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```